# Move files not equal to files in stock folder and older than X

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move files from one folder(`source`) that are NOT in another folder `(stock files`) and where source files are older than 30 days to a backup location

I have tried several times but I can't seem to get it right.

```
$days = 30 
$Source = "G:\fs01\" 
$Destination = "G:\fso2\" 
$StockFileLocation = "g:\fso1Stock\" 
$FileExtention = ".mpr" 
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days) 
$SourceFiles = (Get-ChildItem $Source | where {$_.extension -eq $FileExtention} | % {$_.Name}) 
$StockFiles = (Get-ChildItem $StockFileLocation | where {$_.extension -eq $FileExtention} | % {$_.Name})
```

Goal: for each file in source.
If file name in source < > file name in Stock File Location and
source is older than 30 days then move file to destination.

Comment: I have tried the following: ForEach ($SourceFile in $SourceFiles)
{
    ForEach ($StockFile in $StockFiles)
        {
        If ($SourceFile -eQ $StockFile) 
            {
           
            }
        else 
            {WRITE-HOST $SourceFile}
            #{move-item -path $SourceFile -destination $Destination}
        }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
$days = 30 
$Source = "G:\fs01\" 
$Destination = "G:\fso2\" 
$StockFileLocation = "g:\fso1Stock\" 
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days) 

# get an array of filenames already in the $StockFileLocation folder (names only)
$StockFiles  = Get-ChildItem -Path $StockFileLocation -Filter '*.mpr' -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# get an array of FileInfo objects of .mpr files older that $limit and loop through
$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter '*.mpr' -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit }
$SourceFiles | ForEach-Object {
    if ($StockFiles -notcontains $_.Name) {
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Destination -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch when you are satisfied with the results

---

**Edit**

As requested in your comment, below the same thing wrapped in a function:

```
function Move-OldNotInStock {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('Path')]
        [string[]]$Source,                               # Specifies a path to one or more source locations. Wildcards are accepted.

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]     # The destination folder. Will be created if it does not exist
        [string]$Destination,

        [string]$StockFileLocation = "G:\fso1Stock" ,    # The folder for the files 'in stock'. defaults to "G:\fso1Stock" 
        [int]$AgeInDays = 30,                            # The number of days to consider files old. Defaults to 30
        [string]$FilePattern = '*.mpr',                  # The file pattern of files to collect. Defaults to '*.mpr'
        [switch]$Recurse,                                # Whether or not subfolders in the source path(s) should be included 
        [switch]$WhatIf                                  # 'Chicken switch'. Allows to run the function without actually moving files.
    )    

    # create the destination path if it does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $Destination -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$Destination'"
        New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType 'Directory' -Force | Out-Null
    }

    $limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$AgeInDays)

    # get an array of filenames already in the $StockFileLocation folder (names only)
    $StockFiles  = Get-ChildItem -Path $StockFileLocation -Filter $FilePattern -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

    # get an array of FileInfo objects of .mpr files older that $limit and loop through
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter $FilePattern -File -Recurse:$Recurse | 
        Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit -and $StockFiles -notcontains $_.Name } |
        Move-Item -Destination $Destination -WhatIf:$WhatIf
}
```

Use like this to accept the default values for `-StockFileLocation`, `-AgeInDays`, `-FilePattern`

```
Move-OldNotInStock -Source "G:\fs01" -Destination "G:\fso2" -WhatIf
```

<sup>I have shortened the code to get the files, filter them on age and (non) existance in the stockfolder and removing them a bit. Perhaps this makes the code a little less readable..?</sup>

Comment: Theo. If I may ask. instead of running the code for 20 different locations Is there a way to use this as function and supply the 4 variables?

Comment: @WouterD As requested, I have updated my answer and wrapped it in a reusable function. As extra, the `$Source` parameter can take an array of source folder paths, not just one. Hope you like it.

Comment: Theo again thank you very much. I've ran several tests and each were 100%.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your requirements right, you can do it in a single pipeline

```
$days = 30 
$Source = "G:\fs01\" 
$Destination = "G:\fso2\" 
$StockFileLocation = "g:\fso1Stock\" 
$FileExtention = "*.mpr" 
$limit = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-$days)

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter $FileExtention | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $Limit -and
      (!(Test-Path ($_.FullName -replace [Regex]::Escape($Source),$StockFileLocation)))}|
        Move-Item $Destination -WhatIf
```

If output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

Comment: Swapped `$Destination` and `$StockFiles`, corrected.